# Do strings in C language change in the middle of program execution?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, scanf, c-strings

I was writing the code for Bit stuffing, but I am not getting appropriate answer, when I checked the values of the input string, there was another garbage value added at the end of the string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void input(char[],int);
void stuff(char ch[],int n)
{
    char str1[6]="11111";
    char str2[6]="00000";
    printf("str1=%s\n",str1);
    printf("ch=%s\n",ch);
        if(!strcmp(ch,str1))
        {
            printf("\n111101");
        }
        else if(!strcmp(ch,str2))
        {
            printf("\n000010");
        }
        else
        {
            puts(ch);
        }
}
void main()
{
    int flag=0;
    char ch[5];
    input(ch,5);
    printf("ch0=%s\n",ch); //printing the input string
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
       if((ch[i]!='0')&&(ch[i]!='1'))
       {
           flag=1;
       }
    }

   if(flag==0)
    {
        puts("Entered data:");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",ch[i]);
        }
        puts("\nAfter stuffing");
        printf("ch1=%s\n",ch);    //getting garbage value here
        stuff(ch,5);
    }
    else
    {
         printf("Enter a valid data\n");
    printf("%d",flag);
    }

}
void input(char ch[],int n)
{
    printf("Enter 5 digits\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&ch[i]);
    }

}
```

The output of the code is as follows.

```
Enter 5 digits
11111
ch0=11111

Entered data:
11111
After stuffing
ch1=11111♣
str1=11111
ch=11111♣
11111♣

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.046 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I am using Code blocks IDE with MINGW. The code above should compare the string entered with the given sequence and stuff the bits if all five bits are homogenous.

Comment: You try to read 6 characters into an array that can only hold 5 characters. That is a string of length 4 plus terminating 0 byte. You also do not nul-terminate your input

Comment: ```i<=5``` invokes undefined behaviour because it accesses memory out of bounds.

Comment: Your `input` function is incorrect: it does not terminate `ch` with a null terminator, and it also has array out-of-bounds error. Compile and run with address sanitizer (not available in MinGW, though, only Visual Studio or Linux/macOS) to see more details. If CS50 has a forum, please bring up the issue there as well: it's not the first question I see with a problem from CS50 related to C-style strings lacking null terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lack of null-byte:

A string in `C` is an array of null-terminated bytes. You do not terminate `ch` in the `input` function.

`strcmp` does compare two strings, but it requires them to be null-terminated.

`printf` too requires a null-terminated string with the `%s` format specifier, otherwise it doesn't know when to stop printing. And your code would most probably result in a segmentation fault.

### Accessing memory out of bounds:

This line:

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
```

invokes undefined behaviour because it's writing to out of bounds memory. `ch` has been declared to only contain 5 bytes, which must include the '\0' character.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior. For example you declared a character array with `5` elements in `main`

```
char ch[5];
```

Then you are calling the function `input`

```
input(ch,5);
```

Within the function you are entering `6` characters in the for loop

```
void input(char ch[],int n)
{
    printf("Enter 5 digits\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&ch[i]);
    }

}
```

That is you are overwriting the memory outside the array.

Taking into account the program output

```
Enter 5 digits
11111
ch0=11111
```

the call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%c",&ch[i]);
```

also stored the new line character `'\n'` in the memory after the last element of the array. You should at least write

```
scanf(" %c",&ch[i]);
      ^^^^^
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c",&ch[i]);
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

The array does not contain a string but you are trying to output it as if it contains a string

```
printf("ch0=%s\n",ch); //printing the input string
```

or to use it in calls of `strcmp` as for example

```
if(!strcmp(ch,str1))
```

that again invokes undefined behavior.

To output the array you could use the following format string

```
printf("ch0=%.*s\n", 5, ch); //printing the input string
```

and to compare character arrays you could use either `strncmp` or `memcmp`.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```